# Access a dictionary with json-glib-1.0 in Vala?

Tags: json, glib, vala

I'm trying to access a json dict with json-glib but I can't figure out how to access it following Valadoc

I'm trying to access `files`, the dict looks like this:

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "ABeeZee",
   "category": "sans-serif",
   "variants": [
    "regular",
    "italic"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin"
   ],
   "version": "v12",
   "lastModified": "2019-04-29",
   "files": {
    "regular": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v12/esDR31xSG-6AGleN6tKukbcHCpE.ttf",
    "italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v12/esDT31xSG-6AGleN2tCklZUCGpG-GQ.ttf"
   }
  },
```

Someone can help?

Comment: Your looking for [Json.Object](https://valadoc.org/json-glib-1.0/Json.Object.html) and its get_*_member() methods

Comment: There are some examples here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/JsonSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the deserialization features of `GObject`:

```c
public class Obj : Object {
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string[] variants { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }

    public string to_string () {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
        builder.append_printf ("kind = %s\n", kind);
        builder.append_printf ("family  = %s\n", family);
        builder.append_printf ("category = %s\n", category);
        builder.append_printf(@"variants:[\n");

        foreach (var item in variants) 
            builder.append_printf(@"\t$item\n");

        builder.append_printf(@"]\n");

        return (owned) builder.str;
    }
}

void main (string[] args) {
    string data = """
    {
      "kind" : "my string",
      "family"  : "ABeeZee",
      "category" : "sans-serif",
      "variants": [
        "regular",
        "italic"
      ]
    }""";
    var obj = Json.gobject_from_data (typeof (Obj), data) as Obj;

    print (@"$obj");
}
```

This will output:

```
> vala console.vala --pkg json-glib-1.0
kind = my string
family  = ABeeZee
category = sans-serif
variants:[
        regular
        italic
]
```

Comment: you  need access `files`! I allready know how to access `variants`!

Comment: There like 50 examples how to works with files https://github.com/flobrosch/valadoc-org/tree/master/examples/gio-2.0 
https://github.com/flobrosch/valadoc-org/tree/master/examples/glib-2.0